# What is the diagonalization of ‘∀x¬Gdl(x,y)'?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Correct me if I am wrong here.‘∀x¬Gdl(x,y)' simply states that There does not exist godel number for a given number y, right? So if we say that there exist a diagonalization of ‘∀x¬Gdl(x,y)', then we want to prove that there does exist a godel number for a given y, which leads to contradiction.

So how does it mean that diagonalization of ‘∀x¬Gdl(x,y)' is unprovable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the definition of the relation $Gdl(x,y)$ ?

There is no "godel number" for a given number $y$. Usually, we associate godel numbers to *expressions* of the language; thus, a relation between godel numbers must express a relation between the corresponding expressions of the language, like in :

> $\forall x \lnot Prf_F(x, y)$

where we express the fact that **no** godel number $x$ is the godel number of a *derivation* (that is a sequence of formulae) of the formula with godel number $y$.

---

See [Arithmetization of the Formal Language](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan) into [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/).